# XYZ coordinates of sphere

Tags: java, android

Android beginner, Can anybody guide me on this ?

I do have the distance, angle and origin.

```
newx = (distance * cosθ) + origin.x;
newy = (distance * sinθ) + origin.y;
```

Instead of this is there any default API which I can depend on in Android

Comment: You imply you do have an algorithm // the maths worked out, but are struggling with java/android? If you could add the algorithm and what points you aren't sure of, I'm sure help would be much quicker :).

Comment: SO is not "gimi a code" service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't clear: Are you not understanding Android or the expressions for polar coordinates?

The latter is easy:

```
/**
 * Factory for PointF 
 * @param origin of the coordinate system (not needed)
 * @param distance this really means "radius"
 * @param angle from the x-axis in radians; positive increases in the counterclockwise direction 
 */
public static PointF getPoint(PointF origin, float distance, float angle)
{
    PointF newPoint = new PointF();
    newPoint.x = origin.x + distance*Math.cos(angle);
    newPoint.y = origin.y + distance*Math.sin(angle);
    return newPoint;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some simple trigonometry will help you here if memory serves:

```
public static PointF getPoint(PointF origin, float distance, float angle)
{
  float x = Math.cos(angle)*distance;
  float y = Math.sin(angle)*distance;

  return origin.offset(x,y);
}
```